# Swift UISearchController tableview search result scroll not moving above keyboard upto last row

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchcontroller

In my scenario, I'm using `Tableview` with searchController. The `searchcontroller` will show after search button click. Here, once search controller through search result listing time, if I scroll my tableview, It's not scrolling upto the last 'row' in bottom. I need to show bottom row unto above `keyboard`. I tried below code but not working.

**Button Click to Showing Search Controller**

```
@IBAction func Click_search(_ sender: Any) {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
         searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor =  UIColor.white
        let cancelButtonAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes , for: .normal)
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Inside ViewDidload**

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

**Keyboard  Hide and Show to Adjust Tablview Height**

```
@objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height + 25, right: 0)
        }
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        tableView.contentInset = .zero
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Your are scrolling TableView. Please try to scroll your superview. Its gonna work. try and let me know.

Add bellow code inside of Click_search action.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboard(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboard(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboard(notification:)), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

Call this function to check and scroll your tableView To Up.
//MARK:- Keyboard Check

```
 @objc func keyboard(notification:Notification) {
        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification ||  notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {
           self.view.frame.origin.y = -15
        }else{
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }
```